# Ajax.BeginForm + Updating entire page in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-9, telerik-mvc

I'm using MVC2 and have a telerik popup window in which I'm doing a search and wanting to display the search results in a second tab.

I have my search form in the first tab, on post, I perform the search and have a partialview containing a telerik grid. This works perfectly in Chrome, but when I give it a go in IE9, it shows the search results on a brand new page.

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "DataSearch",
               new AjaxOptions
               {
                   UpdateTargetId = "pnlSearchResults",
                   OnSuccess = "ShowSearchResults",
                   HttpMethod = "Post",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   LoadingElementId = "searchingProgess"
               }))
```

The div, pnlSearchResults is contained in the second tab and is outside of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this had something to do with elements being inside the form. I moved my loading div outside the form, reloaded and it appears to be working just fine now.